# Step by step approach to the analysis of transistor circuits

Tags: transistors, amplifier, small-signal

Below we have a circuit cosisting of three transistors.
Is there any systematic approach to the analysis of such circuits.
We are asked to find the values of  R1 and R2 and aslo the operating point of all transistors.
[image]

Comment: Added homework tag. We should not provide full answers to such questions especially when the poster has not shown any of their own attempts at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the no-calculator method to compute R2.

View that 25Kohm emitter resistor as 40 uA per volt.

We know we need 400uA, thus need 10 volts across the emitter resistor.

Base will be 0.6volt higher, at +0.6 volts.

Voltage across R2 is +10v - +0.6v = 9.6volts.

With beta of 100, you need 4uA. And 4uA is 250,000 ohms per volts.

Now compute the value of R2.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a  systematic approach. First, you must understand how BJT works and know the basis of circuit analysis.

For example. To find the R1 resistor value we need to know the desired voltage drop across R1 resistor.
And from the schematic, I see that \$V_{E1} = V_{B2} + V_{BE} = 8V + 0.6V = 8.6V\$ (the voltage at Q1 emitter)

Hence the voltage at \$Q1\$ base is \$V_{B1} = 8.6V+0.6V = 9.2V\$

And additional we know that:

\$I_{E1} = I_1 + I_{E2} = 0.1mA+\frac{\beta +1}{\beta}\cdot 0.2mA = 0.302mA \$

therefore

\$R_1 = \frac{V_{CC} - V_{B1}}{I_{B1}} = \frac{10V - 9.2V}{\frac{0.302mA}{101}} = 270\textrm{k}\Omega\$

The similar approach can be done to find the \$R_2\$ resistor value.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that no current flows from the middle of those two resistors to the base of the transistor Q2?

Comment: We could include the loading effect if you want. Then VB2 = 7.98V